# Reload promise again after revising the page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1) I have login page and after successful login it goes to home page.

```
if (data.status == CONSTANTS.RETURN_SUCCESS) {
      $location.path("/home");
      $route.reload();
}
```

2) I want to reload some data from database before I go to home page controller - so written promise. Corresponding app.js code:

```
.when('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
        resolve: {
            'myAssetsData': function (myAssetsDataPromise) {
                return myAssetsDataPromise.promise;
            }
        }

    })
```

My promise calls a function "setAssetData()" to fetch & set some service level variables.

```
.service('myAssetsDataPromise', ['myassets_service', '$log', function (myassets_service, $log) {
    $log.debug("Initialize myAssetsDataPromise");
    var return_data = {}
    //fetch and set some service level variables
    var promise = myassets_service.setAssetData()
    return {
        promise: promise,
        getAssets: function () {
            return return_data.status = "success";
        }
    };

}
```

3) Home page has logout link - which simply clears session at server side and redirects to login page

```
$location.path("/");
```

4) Everything works perfectly for the first time. After login, my assets data is loaded first then my home page controller is initialized.

Problem is for the 2nd time loading: What I expected was that if I logout and login back (Or per say go to any other page and come back to home page) then my promise should get executed and asset data should get loaded again. But unless I reload the page Or clear history / cache; my promise does not get executed. I tried  $route.reload() as well but still no luck.

I understand that once promise is resolved, it's not loaded again. But if I leave that page and re-visit again, I want to reload promise again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything should work.
I think problem is because you are assigning result to var

```
var promise = myassets_service.setAssetData()
```

Try to update your code.

```
.service('myAssetsDataPromise', function (myassets_service, $log) {
    return {
        promise: myassets_service.setAssetData()
    };
})


.service('myassets_service', function () {
    return {
        setAssetData : function ($q) {
            var data = {'your_data':'what_ever'};
            console.log('setAssetData called', data);

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried above code (I had to remove $q from inner function and put in above) but still it is same. Promise gets resolved for the first time. After that if I go to any other page and come back to home page, promise is not resolved again. To be safe I want to fetch latest data from database whenever user visits the home page (As chances some other application is also updating db values)